# Existence of a general-purpose (almost) universal optimization strategy

Tags: algorithms, probability-theory, computer-science, optimization

From Wikipedia about [interpretations of no free lunch theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_in_search_and_optimization#Interpretations_of_NFL_results)

> A conventional, but not entirely accurate, interpretation of the NFL
>   results is that "**a general-purpose universal optimization strategy
>   is theoretically impossible**, and the only way one strategy can
>   outperform another is if it is specialized to the specific problem
>   under consideration".[14] Several comments are in order:
>
> **A general-purpose almost-universal optimizer exists theoretically. Each search algorithm performs well on almost all
>   objective functions.**[11]
>
> ...
>
> **For almost all objective functions, specialization is essentially accidental.** Incompressible, or Kolmogorov random,
>   objective functions have no regularity for an algorithm to exploit.
>   Given an incompressible objective function, there is no basis for
>   choosing one algorithm over another. If a chosen algorithm performs
>   better than most, the result is happenstance.[11]

I was wondering

1. How shall I understand that a general-purpose universal optimizer
   doesn't exist but a general-purpose **almost** universal optimizer
   does? What differences are between universal and **almost**
   universal?
2. Do the last two sentences in bold contradict each other? Do "an
   optimizer being almost-universal and perform well on all objective
   functions" and  "it being specialized for almost all objective
   functions" imply each other?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: You may want to take the question to brand-new [cs.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com)!

Comment: Thanks! Is it too theoretical for that new site?

Comment: Not at all, we span *all* CS.

Comment: Is that an 'almost' full employment theorem?

Answer (score 1):

The first quote should not have been published, because the conclusion is categorically wrong. Almost all objective functions are Kolmogorov random. They have no order whatsoever that can be exploited in optimizer design. An optimizer cannot be specialized to one of them. For almost all of the theoretically possible functions on which an optimizer performs well (or poorly), performance has absolutely nothing to do with specialization (or lack thereof).

1. There is "no free lunch" when the optimization result does not, as far as the practitioner can tell, depend on the choice of sampler. This does not mean that the optimization result is bad. When all objective functions are equally likely, modest-sized samples of the objective function, drawn uniformly at random, almost always contain a good value. Because drawing a sample uniformly at random is equivalent to drawing a deterministic (non-random) algorithm uniformly at random, and then applying it, almost all deterministic algorithms perform well on each objective function. See Table 1, p. 16, of the emended version of [my first NFL paper](http://boundedtheoretics.com/EP96.pdf) (1996).
2. The last boldface sentence is self-contradictory, and should be deleted. What I have written here explains why, as do the sentences following it in the article.